# How to connect from Python on Linux server A to Progress OpenEdge DB on Linux server B

Tags: python, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm trying to write a Python routine on "Server A" that can pull data from a Progress (http://www.progress.com) DB on "Server B"... probably via pyodbc, but I'm flexible on the Python side.  Both servers are running Linux OS.

From reading the Progress doc's, it seems the only way to access the Progress DB remotely is to install the Progress ODBC driver's on "Server A".  I'm wondering if there is any other way to achieve a connection from Python to Progress as I'm looking to avoid relying on the proprietary/commercial ODBC drivers (as I realize that's a tall order because Progress is a proprietary/commercial environment).

Has anyone achieved a Python>Progress connection using 'open' solutions?

Comment: It's not any more "open" per say, but I've used the JDBC drivers successfully with JRuby, so Jython+JDBC driver is another possibility.  There's also an [alternative JDBC driver](http://www.ganimede.ro/cms/lang/en-us/products/abl-jdbc/) by Marian Edu, so it's definitely possible to create your own driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a small python interface I wrote way back in ganimede to connect through that 'alternative application server' http://www.ganimede.ro/cms/lang/en-us/open-source/ganimede/

the jdbc driver is using open client to 'talk' with the progress application server, if you have something like that around it can work but won't allow you to connect directly to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree with your reply that there is in fact no way to do this using any pre-canned project.  I ended up rolling my own as well.

Answer (score 0):

If jython is not a problem to use,  you could also try to use jdbc to connect to database.  That will let you connect directly to the db.